# Why is the "default" datasource connection missing when running tests?

Tags: cakephp, testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing tests with fixtures as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-a-test-method).

My bootstrap for tests:

```
if (!getenv('db_dsn')) {
    putenv('db_dsn=sqlite:///:memory:');
}

ConnectionManager::config('test', ['url' => getenv('db_dsn')]);
ConnectionManager::config('test_custom_i18n_datasource', ['url' => getenv('db_dsn')]);
```

My code:

```
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

class BackupExportTest extends TestCase
{
    public $fixtures = ['core.articles', 'core.comments'];

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Articles = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Articles');
    }

    public function testMyFunction()
    {
        $query = $this->Articles->find('all');
    }
}
```

Now, running the test, this is the exception:

```
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 62 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) MysqlBackup\Test\TestCase\Utility\BackupExportTest::testMyFunction
Cake\Datasource\Exception\MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource configuration "default" was not found.

/home/mirko/Libs/Plugins/cakephp-mysql-backup/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/ConnectionManager.php:196
/home/mirko/Libs/Plugins/cakephp-mysql-backup/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:175
/home/mirko/Libs/Plugins/cakephp-mysql-backup/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/TableRegistry.php:110
/home/mirko/Libs/Plugins/cakephp-mysql-backup/tests/TestCase/Utility/BackupExportTest.php:38

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

So, it seems `\Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get()` searchs for `default` connection. Why? How to solve?

---

**EDIT**

`phpunit.xml.dist` is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
    >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="cakephp-mysql-backup Test Cases">
            <directory>./tests/TestCase</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!-- configure code coverage -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

The exception is thrown by running `phpunit` or `phpunit tests/TestCase/Utility/BackupExportTest.php`, via nix terminal. `phpunit` is on `/usr/bin/phpunit` and istalled via deb package.

Comment: What exactly does the command look like that you use to run phpunit? And from where exactly do you run it? Also what does your `phpunit.xml` file look like?

Comment: @ndm I did not understand your first question. File phpunit.xml.dist is [here](https://github.com/mirko-pagliai/cakephp-mysql-backup/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist)

Comment: Please add that the code to your question so that it is self-contained for future readers. With my first question I was asking for the CLI command that you use to run phpunit, and from where in the filesystem and via what kind of CLI (nix terminal, windows default CLI, windows powershell, etc...) you're running it.

Comment: Ok @ndm, I modified the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd better require PHPUnit as a dependency and run it via `vendor/bin/phpunit`, however the actual problem most likely is that you haven't configure the fixture listener.

Quote from the docs:

> Before you can use fixtures you should double check that your
>   `phpunit.xml` contains the fixture listener:
>
> ```
> <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
> <listeners>
>         <listener
>         class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector"
>         file="./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureInjector.php">
>                 <arguments>
>                         <object class="\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
>                 </arguments>
>         </listener>
> </listeners>
> ```

The fixture manager is responsible for creating proper connection aliases, ie mapping non-test connection requests to `test*` connections, like `default` to `test`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Testing > Test Connections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#test-connections)**
- **[Cookbook > Testing > Creating Tests for Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-tests-for-plugins)**

Comment: Yes, this works. Another thing: ensure that your fixtures are loadable. In my case, I'm using fixtures from core. So, in my `composer.json`: `"Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"`